# Eliminate reflectivity towards oncoming traffic headlights

Tags: filters, reflection

I have a couple of adapted commercial CCTV housings mounted on my car roof to do casual facial recognition tracking and license plate tracking. The issue is that the glass on the front of the housings seems to sometimes reflect the headlights if traffic approaching my car at night and there's a very slightly possibility that's not up to state code, or even if it is, it's kind of a dick move.

I'm not a photography aficionado and this might not be the correct place to ask, but is there some kind of filter I can put in front of the housings that will dampen or eliminate this glare?

This is a very similar model before being adapted for use on an SUV.
https://media.merchantcircle.com/31551556/HHC12WM2_hi_full.jpeg

Comment: I'm curious what "casual facial recognition tracking and license plate tracking" entails. Why do you want to casually recognize faces of bystanders or license plates?

Comment: Also, is there a necessity to keep the glass on the camera? It seems not to have any optical function.

Comment: I'd consult a legal professional in your jurisdiction before you get too far into this project. Privacy laws vary wildly from one locality to another, many are very strict and come with massive potential legal liabilities. For example, where I live, you can't legally photograph someone sitting in an outdoor dining venue if there is _any_ kind of barrier (a piece of twine between two posts is sufficient to establish a right to privacy, meaning you can't photograph them without their consent because they are not in "public").

Answer (score 1):

I'm interpreting your question as asking how not to reflect oncoming cars' headlights back at them. The easiest way to deal with that issue is to angle the glass slightly so reflections go somewhere else other than straight back to the oncoming traffic.

You may need to modify the housing slightly depending, but you only need to create a few degrees of tilt, either to the sides, up or down (personally I'd go with down), the goal being to make the glass non-perpendicular to the incoming headlights.

Comment: I’d go up because observation of any reflection is more likely from the ground than the air...well actually I would avoid the whole question by not doing what the person appears to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Standard uncoated glass reflects about 4% per surface. Since there are two sides to a flat glass window that added up to about 8% reflection. An antireflective coating can reduct this to about 1% per surface or less or less than 2% overall. Multilayer coatings can do even better. Look for AR coating windows such as [these from Edmund Optics](https://www.edmundoptics.com/f/lambda4-n-bk7-precision-windows/12267/) or [these](https://jnsglass.com/anti-reflective-anti-glare-glass/). It isn't cheap although there might be cheaper sources. Otherwise, you might try to angle the window down so that you are viewing through it at an angle. This can cause the reflection to not bounce back toward the oncoming cars.